# Add Input Form for Select Category Like Tags

Tags: categories

i have about 200 categories. When I have to publish a post, I select a category one by one. How do I select a category by entering such as adding Tags?

Answer (score 0):

You can add search to list of categories in post editor with this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-category-search/

This plugin is useful when there are a lot of categories.